# how to change varchar date column to a date type column without loseing data

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database which has a column type `varchar` in this column i used to store dates and the format of the dates which  are stored in the form of like this.

formats
`2021-09-21 08:50:27.321002` and `2021-09-21`.
both type of format are used in that column and i don't want to any kind of data.

I want to convert this column into a date type column please if any can tell me how can i do it and i don't want to lose data.
please if any one can help me regarding this.

Comment: You cannot convert `2021-09-21 08:50:27.321002` to a DATE type column without loosing the time portion. So I am not sure I totally understand what you want to do here??

Comment: @RiggsFolly okay i can loose the time but not date of that column how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

IF you mean not losing data, with not losing the microseconds

You need the datatype datetime(5) for that, and a simple coping from your varchar to datetime(5) is no problem, as you have already mysql date forat

> ```
> CREATE TABLe tab1(mydatevar varchar(30), Mydate datetime(5))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES ('2021-09-21 08:50:27.321002',NULL),('2021-09-21',NULL)
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE tab1 SET Mydate = mydatevar
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tab1
> ```
>
> ```
> mydatevar                  | Mydate                   
> :------------------------- | :------------------------
> 2021-09-21 08:50:27.321002 | 2021-09-21 08:50:27.32100
> 2021-09-21                 | 2021-09-21 00:00:00.00000
> ```

> ```
> SELECT MICROSECOND(Mydate) FROM tab1
> ```
>
> ```
> | MICROSECOND(Mydate) |
> | ------------------: |
> |              321000 |
> |                   0 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65f7b5f42991a4c76968cb75bec69273)*